# Php-Conversion of Non-standard timezone to standard

Tags: php, timezone

I have an issue with ics content where Vtimezone,TZID is displayed as Non-standard timezone and need to convert it to standard one.PHP DateTimeZone() function doesnot convert/handle non standard timezones.

ICS content looks like

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST

BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Eastern
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20001105T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:Standard Time
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20000312T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:Daylight Savings Time
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
```

Can anyone please help me to find a solution.....

Answer (score 0):

A good way to solve this might be:

1. Covert your Vtimezone TZID into Unix Timestamp

> Unix time (also known as POSIX time or Epoch time) is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the **number of seconds** that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970

The timestamp you get from this TZID timezone, will be in the format: 
**1459408447**

2. Convert that timestamp to the timezone you need, doing something similar to the following example, for America/Denver:

   ```
   $timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Denver');
   $timestamp = 1459408447;

   $dt = new DateTime( $timezone );    
   $dt->setTimestamp($timestamp);

   echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s (e)');
   ```

Comment: The approach will be also to get a timestamp integer out from your ICS content.